# How to programmatically change the background color while taking photo from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, background-color

Hi i am new to the iOS

I want to programmatically  change **the background color of photo as full white** while taking photo from iPhone,

Is it possible? if so, what i have to do, if any one knows please guide me.

Comment: What would you consider to be the background? You are asking a very complex problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you better have look at [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i downloaded the GPUImage framework but i could not execute. it showing error in **GPUImageBuffer** class

Comment: error message is Receiver type 'GPUImageBuffer' for instance message does not declare a method with selector  'removeTexture'

Comment: By declaring **- (void)removeTexture:(GLuint)textureToRemove;** method in .h file i could fix that error. but it does not open the simulator even build succeeded